# WooCommerce with BlueSnap plugin - What to configure to sell subscriptions?

Tags: woocommerce, woocommerce-subscriptions, bluesnap

I have a store in WooCommerce that works with BlueSnap as a payment gateway. I sell regular one-time charge products, and I'm considering adding a subscription. I was told by BlueSnap that they support payment for subscriptions in WooCommerce - but I couldn't find anything in the plugin documentation to explain how to configure this in my Woo admin.

Should I install a separate plugin for the subscriptions – if so, which one, and which version? Does BlueSnap offer some version of subscription management?

Comment: Nothing will change in your payment gateway settings if is compatible with Woocommerce Subscriptions plugin… The only things to set is the Subscriptions plugin settings itself and your subscription products (to add). For that there is a clear official documentation. As this question is about software settings, is just off-topic on StackOverFlow, so you should remove it, to avoid down votes…

Comment: Isn't this a better question for the BlueSnap Gateway plugin developers? Though my guess is that if the gateway supports it then you only have to set up a subscription product.  I highly recommend setting up a sandbox/test environment and checking it out.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

BlueSnap supports subscriptions in WooCommerce, but in order to use this ability you will need to go through a few steps:

- Install the WooCommerce Subscriptions plugin, version 2.0 and up (2.1 and up is recommended). Make sure it is activated. In the setup menu found in WooCommerce -> Settings -> Subscriptions, configure the plugin as you wish. 
  **Note**: The subscriptions plugin currently allows "Retry Failed Payments" - this is not currently supported by BlueSnap, but it is scheduled for a close release.
- Install and activate the BlueSnap plugin. In the menu found in WooCommerce -> Settings -> Checkout -> BlueSnap Card Payments, Make sure you specify the recurring contract ID.
- Create a subscription product in your WooCommerce store. Once this product is purchased with BlueSnap, the handling of the subscription will be handled automatically.